# Assembly code . = 60^. in low.s file of UNIX V6 source code

Tags: unix, assembly

The source code of UNIX V6 is available and there is a book on it by J.Lions. From the book I know that " . " symbol means current location. I do not understand the next:
"*An assignment statement of the form

identifier = expression

associates a value and type with the identifier. In the example
. = 60^.
the operator ’^’ delivers the value of the first
operand **and** the type of the second operand
(in this case, “location”);*"
The statement can be found in file low.s (0526). What does it mean? Does it actually change PC register value and behaves as a jump instruction? I know it is old code, but I want to understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [6th edition assembler](https://9p.io/7thEdMan/v7vol2b.pdf), `.` is the location counter, an offset from the beginning of a segment (text, data, or bss). When the assembler starts processing a file, `.` in each segment is 0, and is incremented either by assignment to `.` or by the presence of data or instruction statements.

The statement `. = 60^.` means to take the value 60 (in octal), cast it to the type of the location counter (in this case, type `data`), and assign it to the location counter. You'll see several statements like this in `low.s` in the area where interrupt vectors are set up.

When the link editor combines multiple object files together, their text, data, and bss sections are concatenated (except for COMMON data, which gets allocated just once) and any references (such as labels) to instructions or data will be relocated appropriately.

Building the Unix kernel requires an extra step to make sure data meant to be in low memory get loaded at the proper address. After `low.s` and the rest of the Unix kernel object files have been linked together, [sysfix](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/sys/conf/sysfix.c) is [run](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/sys/run) to make the data section have a load address of 0, and to relocate all data references appropriately. So that `. = 60^.` statement has effectively set the location counter to physical address 60.

Comment: Dear Mark. I understand the need to place the data at certain physical address. But what is confusing is such sophisticated expression   . = 60^ . From the book you provided I found that location counter may not be decreased. But anyway. Why not to just add 60 to location counter? Or just to set it equal 60? Instead in low.c file "or" operator is used.

Comment: P.S. Sorry, my fault! It is not "or" operator. Quote from the book: "ˆ result has the value of first operand and the type of the second; most often used to define new
machine instructions with syntax identical to existing instructions."

Comment: @Shkodzer Having offsets be typed (text, data, bss) is an elegant way to work with segmented memory that you find on systems like the PDP-11. You can have a label of type `text` whose value is the address of a chunk of code, and can use it in a statement in the data section (as part of an array of function addresses in C, in an interrupt vector, etc.), and it'll be relocated appropriately by the linker. That being said, requiring syntax like `. = 60^.` seems overly verbose. I would hope the assembler authors also allow `. = 60`, since the intent is clear, but I don't know if it works or not.